# Como borrar todo el contenido del canvas en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

He estado buscando la solución para este problema, me ninguno se adecua a la forma en la que escribí mi código.
Lo que quiero hacer es tener un botón que al oprimirlo se borre todo el contenido del canvas sin borrar o desaparecer los bordes negros que ya tenía. Esto me gustaria hacer lo con javascript puro

```js
const texto = document.getElementById("texto_lineas");
const boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");

boton.addEventListener("click", dibujoPorClick);
texto.addEventListener("keyup", enter);

let d = document.getElementById("dibujito");
let ancho = d.width;
let lienzo = d.getContext("2d");

dibujar("black", 1, 0, 0, 300);
dibujar("black", 1, 300, 300, 300);

function dibujar(color, x_incial, y_incial, x_final, y_final) {
  lienzo.beginPath();
  lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
  lienzo.moveTo(x_incial, y_incial);
  lienzo.lineTo(x_final, y_final);
  lienzo.stroke();
  lienzo.closePath();
}

function dibujoPorClick() {
  let lineas = parseInt(texto.value);
  let l = 0;
  let yi, xf;
  let colorcito = "#ffbcff";
  let espacio = ancho / lineas;

  for (l = 0; l < lineas; l++) {
    yi = espacio * l;
    xf = espacio * (l + 1);
    dibujar(colorcito, 0, yi, xf, 300);
  }
}

function enter(evento) {
  if (evento.keyCode == 13) {
    dibujoPorClick();
  }
}
```

```html
    <h1>Dibujo en canvas</h1>
    <p>
        ¿Cuntas lineas quieres?
        <input type="text" placeholder="Dime cuantas lienas quieres" id="texto_lineas">
        <button id="botoncito">Dibuja las Lineas</button>
        <button id="reset">Clear</button>
    </p>

    <canvas width="300" height="300" id="dibujito"></canvas>
```

Comment: Pinta un recuadro blanco en las coordenadas adecuadas.

Answer (score 1):

Pues puedes usar clearRect para limpiar todo lo que hay en tu canvas, siguiendo tu código puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
const botonBorrar = document.getElementById("reset");
botonBorrar.addEventListener("click", limpiarCanvas);
function limpiarCanvas() {
   lienzo.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
   dibujar("black", 1, 0, 0, 300);
   dibujar("black", 1, 300, 300, 300);
}
```

Esto limpia todo lo que hay en el canvas y luego vuelve a dibujar los bordes negros